# Is `env` not to print out the environment in the current shell, but the environment received within `env`?

Tags: environment-variables

coreutils manual says about `env` command that

> ```
> env [option]... [name=value]... [command [args]...]
> ```
>
> If no command name is specified following the environment specifications, the resulting
>   environment is printed. This is like specifying the printenv program.

is the printed environment by `env` specific to `env`, in the sense that the value of `_` depends on `env`? For example,

```
$ env | grep '^_'
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Does `env` print out almost all the the exported environment of the current shell, except that the value of the environment variable `_` is modified to be specific to `env`?

So is `env` not to print out the environment in the current shell, but the environment received within `env`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

env is a separate program in most shells, so it prints the environment it received from the shell.

The Bourne Shell uses an environment management system based on shell variables.

At startup, it imports the environment into the list of shell variables.

Creating or modifying shell variables does not modify the environment that the shell sets up for new programs.

- calling `set` prints the **internal shell variables** as `set` is built into the shell
- calling `env` prints the **exported environment** as `env` is an external command

The shell variable `_` was introduced by `ksh88`. It holds the last command.

Comment: thanks. is 'the environment it received from the shell' different from the environment which a command different from `env` received from the shell, because the value of `_` is command-specific?

Comment: I edited the answer to be more verbose

Comment: Thanks. Does `env` print out almost all the the exported environment of the current shell, except that the value of the environment variable `-` is modified to be specific to `env`? See the exampled I added to my post.

Comment: `env`prints everything it received from the shell.

Comment: sorry, in my last comment, I meant the value of the environment variable `_`, instead of `-`, is modified to be specific to `env`. So doesn't the value of `_` in the output of `env` depend on `env`, and not on the current shell?

Comment: No, the shell just creates a new environment from the shell variables (by looking at the epxort attributes) for every new external command.

Comment: So is the output of `env` the environment that the shell passes to `env`? Does the environment that `env` receives contain environment variables whose values are specific to `env`, such as  `_` whose value is set to `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: `env` is not part of the shell.