# When is `_` an environment variable of a bash shell?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Bash Manual says (manpage, my emphasis):

> When Bash invokes an external command, the variable `$_` is set to the full pathname
>   of the command and **passed to that command in its environment.**

And (*Special Parameters*):

> ### `_`
>
> (`$_` , an underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute
>   pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment
>   or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous
>   command, after expansion. Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment exported to that command.
>   When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file.

1. In a bash shell, I run:

   ```
   $ bash
   $ export | grep '_='
   ```

   According to the manual, `_` should be an environment variable of
   the new bash shell. `export` is supposed to output all the
   environment variables of the new bash shell, but it doesn't output
   `_`.  So I wonder whether `_` is an environment variable of the new
   bash shell?
2. Actually in any bash shell, the same thing happens

   ```
   $ export | grep '_='
   ```

   doesn't output anything. So I wonder if `_` is ever an environment
   variable of a bash shell?
3. For comparison:

   ```
   $ dash
   $ export  | grep '_='        
   export _='/bin/dash'
   ```

My post is inspired by [Mike's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436603/is-there-a-bash-builtin-command-which-can-show-the-environment-variables-of-the#comment788935_436605) and [Stephane's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280557/674).

Comment: It's a shell variable, and it's passed to _the command's_ environment; it's not necessarily exported to _the shell's_ environment.  `export` is a builtin, but if you use `printenv _`, it will show you how it was invoked: `/usr/bin/printenv` on this system.

Comment: Note that `bash -c export | grep _=` (from Bash), *will* show how the parent shell invoked the `bash` command, even though `$_` is unset in the parent.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293302/ .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `_` is an environment variable of the new Bash shell; you can see that by running

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$$/environ | grep _=
```

inside the shell: that shows the contents of the shell’s initial environment. You won’t see it in the first shell because there wasn’t a previous shell to set it before it started.

Expanding `$_` inside Bash refers to the `_` special parameter, which expands to the last argument of the previous command. (Internally Bash handles this by using a `_` shell variable, which is updated every time a command is parsed, but that’s really an implementation detail. [It is “unexported” every time a command is parsed.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437263/674)) `export` doesn’t show `_` because it isn’t a variable which is marked as exported; you can however see it in the output of `set`.

In the first example, the new Bash shell parses and executes the commands in its startup files, so when running `export | grep '_='`, `_` has already been overwritten and marked as not exported.

In the `dash` example, it doesn't seem to execute any start-up file, so you’re seeing the variable as an environment variable that was set by Bash before running `dash`.

Comment: Thanks. In the new bash shell, why doesn't `export | grep '_='` output anything? In the original bash shell, why doesn't `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$$/environ | grep _=` output anything?

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering [why and when `_` is dropped out of the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437263/674), and [how I can export it back to the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437185/674)?

Answer (score 9):

[`export` without arguments lists all exported *variables*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-export).  `_` is not a variable, but is listed as a [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_005f).

Somewhat confusingly, `_` would also be [a valid name for a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-name), unlike the names of the other special parameters. At least Bash 4.4 allows assignments to it, without complaints. It's just not useful because the special effect immediately overrides the value.

Comment: Have fun trying to use `_` as a variable though ;-). It’s effectively write-only and the value is lost immediately.

Comment: Also, internally Bash does treat `_` as a variable, which is why it appears in the output of `set`. However it can’t be marked as exported as far as I can determine.

Comment: @StephenKitt, but Bash 4.4 allows marking it read-only. Or an integer. With somewhat hilarious results.

Comment: Ha, nice find, that’s rather amusing!

Answer (score 6):

Not every shell variable es marked as exported as you can see in the output of `declare -p`.

It does not make any sense for `bash` to mark `$_` as exported because it automatically adds this variable to the environment of child processes **but** with a different value than the one it has in the shell (at that moment).

Showing it as exported would just confuse the user about what is going to happen with the environment of external commands.

All the "runtime variables" `BASH*` are not exported.