# why can't `_` be exported to the environment of bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In bash, why can't `_` be exported to the environment of the shell?

```
$ export _
$ export | grep _=
$
```

output nothing. Or do I miss something?

How can I export `_` into the environment?

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436615/when-is-an-environment-variable-of-a-bash-shell#comment788962_436623). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_` is a special parameter, like `$1`, `$-` etc. It happens to be implemented as a variable in Bash, but it shouldn’t be thought of as such. See [the special parameters section in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html):

> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.

Special parameters *are not* variables.

You can’t export it because Bash enforces that: every time a command is parsed, [the exported flag is cleared on the `_` variable](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3836).

Comment: Thanks. "assignment to them is not allowed." Is it also that exporting all the special parameters (not just `_`) is not allowed?

Comment: Special parameters are not variables, so they can’t be exported.

Comment: `_` is a special parameter, and bash can export it when executing an external executable or script. Do you mean all special parameters except `_` in that case can't be exported?

Comment: No, `_` is a special parameter, and special parameters aren’t exported. Bash separately places a variable named `_`, storing the path of the command being run, into child process’ environments when they start. I know the manual mixes everything up in the description of the `_` special parameter, but it’s easier to understand (and closer to reality) to think of the `_` special parameter on the one hand, and the `_` variable exported to commands on the other.

Comment: special parameter `_` and variable `_` can't exit at the same time, correct?

Comment: They’re different things, so in theory they could exist at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$_` is a special parameter of the Bash shell, not a generic variable.

Related question: [When is `_` an environment variable of a bash shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436615/when-is-an-environment-variable-of-a-bash-shell)

Comment: How can I export it then?

Comment: I imagine you could copy its content to a variable `$FOO`, then export the latter.

Comment: Does `export` not work with any special parameter? Where in the official document does it say so?