# When is `_` dropped out of the environment?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

```
$ bash --norc
$ export | grep '_='
declare -x _="/bin/bash"
$ export | grep '_='
$
```

What happens to `_`? Is it dropped out of the environment immediately when?

This is related to my other question, "[why can't `_` be exported to the environment of bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437185/674)".

Comment: Not actually duplicate. different questions.

Comment: I will delete the second part of the question (which _is_ a duplicate) and try to re-open.

Comment: The reason I linked the other post, is that I and anyone else will not forget to read them both and get a fuller understanding any time in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, `_` is a special parameter which is set to the value of the last argument every time a command is parsed. It also has the special property of not being exportable, which is enforced every time a command is executed (see [`bind_lastarg` in the Bash source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3836)).

When you start Bash using `bash --norc`, you get to the prompt without having executed any command; so `_`, if it was present in the environment, has not been overwritten. When you start Bash from Bash, the parent Bash sets `_` to the command being run in the child’s environment before starting it; like any other variable present in the environment at startup, `_` therefore ends up being an exported variable, and since no command has been run, that variable hasn’t been “unexported”. This explains why your first `export` contains it.

As soon as you run a command (your first `export` in this case), `_` is overwritten and loses its exported flag. This explains why your second `export` doesn’t show it.

(Internally, `_` is a variable like any other; so it can be set read-only or marked as an integer, with amusing results.)

Comment: Thanks. Normally, when we reassign a value to an environment parameter, the parameter remains in the environment but with a different value. So what makes `_` not behave like that?

Comment: when starting `bash --norc`, `_` is in the environment of the new shell, so it has the exported flag. But it also has the property of not being exportable. How can I check both exported flag and non-explorable property?  Do they co-exist on `_` all the time?

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Does the same thing happen to other parameters, besides `_` ?

Comment: No; other parameters aren’t variables anyway.

Comment: "It also has the special property of not being exportable, which is enforced every time a command is executed". When a bash process executes a command, if bash doesn't add `_` to its own environment, why does it need to drop it from its own environment? (That is also the motivation of [my new post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437380/is-a-temporary-environment-variable-added-before-or-after-the-shell-creates-a-ch))