# Is a temporary environment variable added before or after the shell creates a child process which will execute a command?

Tags: bash

In bash, when running

```
myvar=val mycommand myargs
```

`myvar=val` will be added to the environment for executing `mycommand`.

Suppose the the bash process calls `fork()` to create a child process which will executes `mycommand`, i.e. `mycommand` is an external executable file or a script file.

When does adding `myvar=val` to the environment happen, before or after the bash shell calls `fork()`? In other words, which of the following two possibilities actually happens?

- the bash process adds `myvar=val`  to its own environment, then calls `fork()` to create a child process which will calls `execve()` to execute `mycommand`, and `myvar=val` as part of the environment of the bash process is inherited into the environment of the child process. Upon finishing the execution of `mycommand` and exiting of the child process, the bash process drops `myvar=val` from its own environment.
- the bash process calls `fork()` to create a child process which will executes `mycommand`, and the child process adds `myvar=val` to its own environment and then calls `execve()` to execute `mycommand`.

My question is motivated from [Stephen's reply to my earlier post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437266/674).

> In Bash, `_` is a special parameter which is set to the value of the last argument every time a command is parsed. It also has the special property of not being exportable, which is enforced every time a command is executed (see [`bind_lastarg` in the Bash source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3836)).

I am wondering that when a bash process executes a command, if bash doesn't add `_` to its own environment, why does it need to drop it from its own environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Bash may have inherited `_` as an environment variable. Every time a command is executed, the "exported" flag on the variable is cleared. You would think that, once the bit has been cleared, there is no need to clear it again, but it is cheaper and simpler to just clear it instead of doing a test and clear.

Comment: I tend to think there is no "own" bash environment. There's just a bunch of variables, each with the "export" flag set or clear. When an external command is run, bash allocates a new array and copies the exported variables into this array, which is passed as the `envp` parameter to the `execve` system call. The kernel then copies the array onto the child process's stack, next to the argument vector that `argv` points to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reality is somewhere between the two possibilities you describe. Bash doesn’t add `myvar` to its own environment, at least not the full shell environment as we usually think of it; it adds `myvar` to its *temporary* environment. It then builds the export environment, specifically for the new command, from the temporary environment, along with the current variable context, and the shell functions, *before* forking if necessary to run the child command. You can see this as [calls to `maybe_make_export_env` in the Bash source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n4090). The temporary environment is then cleaned up after the child is started; look for `dispose_used_env_vars`.

In practice this doesn’t make any difference. The child command gets the environment it’s supposed to receive, and the parent environment is at it should be too once you get control back; unless you’re going to make changes to Bash, that’s all that matters.

Comment: Thanks. "The reality is somewhere between the two possibilities you describe" is a little ambiguous. Is the reality the same as the first possibility I described, and not the second possibility?

Comment: No, like I said it’s somewhere in between. The assignment never makes it to the shell environment, it’s limited to the temporary environment (AFAICT from a quick read). Of course in practice the effect is the same as your first possibility.

Comment: I’ll try to clarify...

Comment: In "The environment is then cleaned up after the child is started", do you mean the temporary environment instead of the the shell's environment, by "The environment"?

Comment: @Tim You are really looking into too much detail here, imho. Environment variables are reall just a parameter passing mechanism, similar to the argument vector `argv`. There are rules set by Bash and other standards that the environment variables are inherited by child processes, but how this is done is an implementation detail. There is no rigid data structure "The environment" that is floating somewhere in the background that is magically passed from process to process.

Comment: See my preivious answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436603/is-there-a-bash-builtin-command-which-can-show-the-environment-variables-of-the/436631#436631

Comment: @Johan: see my edit about why I asked the questions.

Comment: Stephen, Thanks. I really like the links you gave to the C implementation of bash. If I would like to read the C code, I was wondering how I can find out  the definition of a function e.g. `dispose_used_env_vars`? Do I need to download the source code, and use `grep`, or can I search directly on the website?

Comment: I always prefer downloading source code to read it, either from the upstream repository, or from the Debian archives (`apt source`). That way I can use `etags` etc. to simplify navigation in Emacs.

Comment: "The temporary environment is then cleaned up after the child is started", which seems a waste. I wonder why not let the child process to prepare its own environment instead of letting the original bash shell process prepares for it? Normally, when one writes a C program doing some similar thing, will they let the original process or the child process to prepare the environment of the child?

Comment: @Tim Like I said earlier, the process environment is really just a parameter passing mechanism. The parent process passes an environment to its child process. This environment can be equivalent to what has been passed to the parent by the parent's parent, or it can be different. The child cannot construct its own environment out of thin air, it has to come from somewhere. This "somewhere" is what is pointed to by the `envp` pointer in the `execve` system call. There is no other mechanism.

Comment: @Johan: when a process calls `execve()` to run a program, it doesn't create a new process. Before calling `execve()`, the process can prepare a new environment as argument given to `execve()`, instead of letting its parent process do so. Do you agree?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. It's the child process that does the exec, so it can construct the environment, although I am not very convinced the savings are very big.

Comment: @Tim the shell still has to be able to construct and clean up a temporary environment, because it might end up with *no* child to start (think of *e.g.* built-in commands).