# Why is my variable available through echo, but not through printenv?

Tags: environment-variables

When first installing powerlevel10k, one usually follows the guides available on the Internet and clone the repository inside oh-my-zsh's folder:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k
```

Now, if I `echo $ZSH_CUSTOM` I will get `/home/myuser/.oh-my-zsh/custom` as expected, but `printenv` will not list it at all. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is \`env\` not to print out the environment in the current shell, but the environment received within \`env\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293302/is-env-not-to-print-out-the-environment-in-the-current-shell-but-the-environm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:-` in the variable tells bash (or zsh) to use whatever is after the `-` as the default value. If `ZSH_CUSTOM` is not in your environment variables (it doesn't show up in `printenv`), it will default to `$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom`.

You can try it yourself:

```bsh
echo ${MY_VARIABLE}
# prints an empty line
echo ${MY_VARIABLE:-a default value}
# prints: a default value
```